# AngularCli strict NPM versions?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, package.json

Is it possible to setup **AngularCli** so that it will generate **package.json** with **strict versions**?

Not:

```
"@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
```

But

```
"@angular/common": "6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "6.0.3",
```

I'd tried

```
npm config set save-exact true
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can...
I think some related materials are:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/strict-version

can you post why npm config set save-exact true failed?
perhaps it isn't installed.

You can also try.... npm install --save --save-exact my-module@my-specific-version

Also--it may be useful to add that if you only want to do this for a specific package, you can add --save-exact to the command line. 
Eg, npm install --save --save-exact somepackage